# Different datasets for table and graph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm showing a table with only actuals from week x, while below the actuals i'm showing a graph with the same data but then over 13 periods (x-13)

Performance wise, would you use 2 datasets for each object? Or would you use 1 dataset and filter the table on the last week?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the query is pretty intensive, it will obviously be quicker to call it once and filter in the report. Same is true if the connection is slow, or if the server performance is awful.

However, if the client machine runs like a dog (or the report server), then you might fare better calling 2 different queries.